# Cannot Invoke() Handlers Located in Content Page from ContentView using Data Template Selector .Net MAUI

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I cannot figure out, the code on the ContentView is supposed to Invoke() the same method on the page that I included this control. I set up the DataTemplateSelector this way but the Handlers are not Invoking the C# code on the ContentPage. Everything else works:

```
    <ContentPage
    x:Class="NiceApp.Views.HomePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:NiceApp.Views.FeedTemplates"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:NiceApp.Views">



<ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PostTextOnly">
            <templates:PostFeedTextOnly />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="PostAndImage">
            <templates:PostFeedWithImage />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="PostAndVideo">
            <templates:PostFeedWithVideo />
        </DataTemplate>

        <templates:FeedDataTemplateSelector
            x:Key="FeedDataTemplateSelector"
            OnDisplayCard="DisplayUserCardAsync"
            OnDisplayUserProfile="DisplayUserProfileAsync"
            PostTextOnlyTemplate="{StaticResource PostTextOnly}"
            PostWithImageTemplate="{StaticResource PostAndImage}"
            PostWithVideoTemplate="{StaticResource PostAndVideo}" />

    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

```
 <CollectionView
                    x:Name="CvHomeVoicers"
                    HeightRequest="670"
                    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FeedDataTemplateSelector}"
                    Scrolled="OnCollectionViewScrolled"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="10" Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                    <CollectionView.Footer>
                        <VerticalStackLayout
                            Margin="3"
                            Padding="3"
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="Loader" IsRunning="False" />

                            <Button
                                Padding="5"
                                Clicked="LoadItemsIncrementallyAsync"
                                HeightRequest="40"
                                MinimumWidthRequest="200"
                                Style="{StaticResource BlackButton}"
                                Text="Load More"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </CollectionView.Footer>

                </CollectionView>
```

```
internal class FeedDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector

{
        public DataTemplate PostTextOnlyTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate PostWithImageTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate PostWithVideoTemplate { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnDisplayCard ;
        public event EventHandler<TappedEventArgs> OnDisplayUserProfile;


  protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            
            var post = (UserHomeModel)item;          

            if (post.FileMimeType == ".jpg")            {               

                    return PostWithImageTemplate;
            }
            else if(post.EmbedLink != null && post.EmbedLink != string.Empty)   
            {  
                if(post.EmbedLink.Contains("/video"))
                {
                    return PostWithVideoTemplate;
                }
                    //play video on app video control
                    return PostTextOnlyTemplate ;
            } 
            else
            {
                return PostTextOnlyTemplate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{

    public string Userid { get; set; } 
    bool isLoading;
    public ObservableCollection<UserHomeModel> Items { get; set; } = new                   ObservableCollection<UserHomeModel>(); 
   
   
    public HomePage()
        
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    
        //call methods
        Userid = LoggedUser.UserId;
        GetPeople(Userid);
        _ = LoadItemsFirstTimeInCollectionViewAsync(Userid);
               
    }
         
    public async Task LoadItemsFirstTimeInCollectionViewAsync(string Userid)
    {
                 
       var comments = await ApiUserHome.GetHomePageInitialComments(Userid, "home", 10);

        Loader.IsRunning = true;

        foreach (var comment in comments)
        {            
            Items.Add(comment);
        }
        CvHomeVoicers.ItemsSource = Items;

        Loader.IsRunning = false;
    }

 private async void DisplayUserProfileAsync(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parameter = e.Parameter;      
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new UserProfile(parameter.ToString(), 0));
    }

private void DisplayUserCardAsync(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parameter = e.Parameter;       
        MopupService.Instance.PushAsync(new ProfileCard(parameter.ToString()));
    }


 }
}
```

**This is one of the ContentView Controls that I am loading with the DataTemplateSelector**

```
<Image
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="0,2,5,5"
                    HeightRequest="50"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    Source="{Binding FullProfilePhotoUrl}"
                    Style="{StaticResource AvatarImageStyle}"
                    WidthRequest="50">
                    <Image.Clip>
                        <EllipseGeometry
                            Center="25,25"
                            RadiusX="25"
                            RadiusY="25" />
                    </Image.Clip>
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding CreatorId}" Tapped="DisplayUserCardAsync" />

                        <!--<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="DisplayUserCardAsync" Command="{Binding BindingContext.ItemTapped,
                            Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Reference CvHomeVoicers}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding CreatorId}"/>-->

                        <!--<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="DisplayUserCardAsync"
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.ItemTapped, Source={x:Reference CvHomeVoicers}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding CreatorId}"></TapGestureRecognizer>-->

                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
```

```
<ContentView
    x:Class="NiceApp.Views.FeedTemplates.PostFeedTextOnly"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:NiceApp.Views">

    <Frame
        Padding="5"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        BorderColor="Transparent"
        CornerRadius="0">
        <Grid RowSpacing="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        
            <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Spacing="5">

                <Image
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="0,2,5,5"
                    HeightRequest="50"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    Source="{Binding FullProfilePhotoUrl}"
                    Style="{StaticResource AvatarImageStyle}"
                    WidthRequest="50">
                    <Image.Clip>
                        <EllipseGeometry
                            Center="25,25"
                            RadiusX="25"
                            RadiusY="25" />
                    </Image.Clip>
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>                       
                      
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="DisplayUserCardAsync"
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.ItemTapped, Source={x:Reference        CvHomeVoicers}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding CreatorId}"></TapGestureRecognizer>

                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>

  </HorizontalStackLayout>


public partial class PostFeedTextOnly : ContentView
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnDisplayCard;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnDisplayUserProfile;

    public PostFeedTextOnly()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DisplayUserCardAsync(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        OnDisplayCard?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void DisplayUserProfileAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnDisplayUserProfile?.Invoke(this, e);  
    }
}
```

The three layouts have several TapGestureRecognizer but they are not Invoking() the content page.
Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: *"they are not Invoking() the content page"* - Break the problem down into several steps, so you can determine exactly where it goes wrong. Is OnDisplayCard not set correctly? Are you able to display a page, if you make a button and "hardwire" it to show the page? Its best to get complicated code to work one step at a time. Get to the point where you can say "if I do ..., it works", but then when I do ..., nothing happens".